# Exporting Scraped Email Text to Excel with XLWings

Tags: python, xlwings

I've put together a script to scrape the contents of unread emails. That works ok. I am now trying to export the scraped data to an open Excel workbook. I have done this before with XLWings but cannot seem to get it to work here for some reason.

Can anyone see the issue?

```
import xlwings as xw
from imap_tools import MailBox, AND

def getEmail():
    with MailBox('imap.gmail.com').login('*****@gmail.com', '*****.', 'INBOX') as mailbox:
        for msg in mailbox.fetch(AND(from_='*****@gmail.com', seen=False)):
            print(msg.subject)
            body = msg.text or msg.html
            print(body.strip())
            return (body)

def exportExcel():

    todays_ps = getEmail()
    wb = xw.Book('ExportEmailTest.xlsm')
    sht2 = wb.sheets['Sheet2']
    sht2.range('A1').options(index=False).value = todays_ps

getEmail()
exportExcel()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don’t login as mailbox. Try as admin or something. Not sure though

Comment: Hi @Brett, Welcome to StackOverflow. Please try to add this as a comment.